# Derive Avro schema from Scala case class generated by ScalaPB

Tags: scala, avro, scalapb, avro4s

I'm trying to derive Avro Schema from [ScalaPB](https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB) generated case class (from Protobuf definition) using [Avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s), but couldn't succeed. The example below shows the problem.

My protobuf file `test.proto`:

```
message Test {

// Unix timestamp in milliseconds
required int64 time_ms = 1;

// user_id
optional string UUID = 2;
}
```

I generate `Test` case class using ScalaPB:

```
// Generated by the Scala Plugin for the Protocol Buffer Compiler.
// Do not edit!
//
// Protofile syntax: PROTO2

package test

/** @param timeMs
  *   Unix timestamp in milliseconds
  * @param uUID
  *   user_id
  */
@SerialVersionUID(0L)
final case class Test(
    timeMs: _root_.scala.Long,
    uUID: _root_.scala.Option[_root_.scala.Predef.String] = None
    ) extends scalapb.GeneratedMessage with scalapb.Message[Test] with scalapb.lenses.Updatable[Test] {
    @transient
    private[this] var __serializedSizeCachedValue: _root_.scala.Int = 0
    private[this] def __computeSerializedValue(): _root_.scala.Int = {
      var __size = 0

      {
        val __value = timeMs
        __size += _root_.com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeInt64Size(1, __value)
      };
      if (uUID.isDefined) {
        val __value = uUID.get
        __size += _root_.com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeStringSize(2, __value)
      };
      __size
    }
    final override def serializedSize: _root_.scala.Int = {
      var read = __serializedSizeCachedValue
      if (read == 0) {
        read = __computeSerializedValue()
        __serializedSizeCachedValue = read
      }
      read
    }
    def writeTo(`_output__`: _root_.com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream): _root_.scala.Unit = {

      {
        val __v = timeMs
        _output__.writeInt64(1, __v)
      };
      uUID.foreach { __v =>
        val __m = __v
        _output__.writeString(2, __m)
      };
    }
    def mergeFrom(`_input__`: _root_.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream): test.Test = {
      var __timeMs = this.timeMs
      var __uUID = this.uUID
      var __requiredFields0: _root_.scala.Long = 0x1L
      var _done__ = false
      while (!_done__) {
        val _tag__ = _input__.readTag()
        _tag__ match {
          case 0 => _done__ = true
          case 8 =>
            __timeMs = _input__.readInt64()
            __requiredFields0 &= 0xfffffffffffffffeL
          case 18 =>
            __uUID = Option(_input__.readString())
          case tag => _input__.skipField(tag)
        }
      }
      if (__requiredFields0 != 0L) { throw new _root_.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException("Message missing required fields.") } 
      test.Test(
          timeMs = __timeMs,
          uUID = __uUID
      )
    }
    def withTimeMs(__v: _root_.scala.Long): Test = copy(timeMs = __v)
    def getUUID: _root_.scala.Predef.String = uUID.getOrElse("")
    def clearUUID: Test = copy(uUID = None)
    def withUUID(__v: _root_.scala.Predef.String): Test = copy(uUID = Option(__v))
    def getFieldByNumber(__fieldNumber: _root_.scala.Int): _root_.scala.Any = {
      (__fieldNumber: @_root_.scala.unchecked) match {
        case 1 => timeMs
        case 2 => uUID.orNull
      }
    }
    def getField(__field: _root_.scalapb.descriptors.FieldDescriptor): _root_.scalapb.descriptors.PValue = {
      _root_.scala.Predef.require(__field.containingMessage eq companion.scalaDescriptor)
      (__field.number: @_root_.scala.unchecked) match {
        case 1 => _root_.scalapb.descriptors.PLong(timeMs)
        case 2 => uUID.map(_root_.scalapb.descriptors.PString).getOrElse(_root_.scalapb.descriptors.PEmpty)
      }
    }
    def toProtoString: _root_.scala.Predef.String = _root_.scalapb.TextFormat.printToUnicodeString(this)
    def companion = test.Test
}

object Test extends scalapb.GeneratedMessageCompanion[test.Test] {
  implicit def messageCompanion: scalapb.GeneratedMessageCompanion[test.Test] = this
  def fromFieldsMap(__fieldsMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[_root_.com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, _root_.scala.Any]): test.Test = {
    _root_.scala.Predef.require(__fieldsMap.keys.forall(_.getContainingType() == javaDescriptor), "FieldDescriptor does not match message type.")
    val __fields = javaDescriptor.getFields
    test.Test(
      __fieldsMap(__fields.get(0)).asInstanceOf[_root_.scala.Long],
      __fieldsMap.get(__fields.get(1)).asInstanceOf[_root_.scala.Option[_root_.scala.Predef.String]]
    )
  }
  implicit def messageReads: _root_.scalapb.descriptors.Reads[test.Test] = _root_.scalapb.descriptors.Reads{
    case _root_.scalapb.descriptors.PMessage(__fieldsMap) =>
      _root_.scala.Predef.require(__fieldsMap.keys.forall(_.containingMessage == scalaDescriptor), "FieldDescriptor does not match message type.")
      test.Test(
        __fieldsMap.get(scalaDescriptor.findFieldByNumber(1).get).get.as[_root_.scala.Long],
        __fieldsMap.get(scalaDescriptor.findFieldByNumber(2).get).flatMap(_.as[_root_.scala.Option[_root_.scala.Predef.String]])
      )
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Expected PMessage")
  }
  def javaDescriptor: _root_.com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor = TestProto.javaDescriptor.getMessageTypes.get(0)
  def scalaDescriptor: _root_.scalapb.descriptors.Descriptor = TestProto.scalaDescriptor.messages(0)
  def messageCompanionForFieldNumber(__number: _root_.scala.Int): _root_.scalapb.GeneratedMessageCompanion[_] = throw new MatchError(__number)
  lazy val nestedMessagesCompanions: Seq[_root_.scalapb.GeneratedMessageCompanion[_]] = Seq.empty
  def enumCompanionForFieldNumber(__fieldNumber: _root_.scala.Int): _root_.scalapb.GeneratedEnumCompanion[_] = throw new MatchError(__fieldNumber)
  lazy val defaultInstance = test.Test(
    timeMs = 0L
  )
  implicit class TestLens[UpperPB](_l: _root_.scalapb.lenses.Lens[UpperPB, test.Test]) extends _root_.scalapb.lenses.ObjectLens[UpperPB, test.Test](_l) {
    def timeMs: _root_.scalapb.lenses.Lens[UpperPB, _root_.scala.Long] = field(_.timeMs)((c_, f_) => c_.copy(timeMs = f_))
    def uUID: _root_.scalapb.lenses.Lens[UpperPB, _root_.scala.Predef.String] = field(_.getUUID)((c_, f_) => c_.copy(uUID = Option(f_)))
    def optionalUUID: _root_.scalapb.lenses.Lens[UpperPB, _root_.scala.Option[_root_.scala.Predef.String]] = field(_.uUID)((c_, f_) => c_.copy(uUID = f_))
  }
  final val TIME_MS_FIELD_NUMBER = 1
  final val UUID_FIELD_NUMBER = 2
}
```

Then try to derive the Avro Schema as below:

```
val schema = AvroSchema[Test]
```

I get the below error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter schemaFor: com.sksamuel.avro4s.SchemaFor[test.Test]
```

How can I succeed here? Is there any other utility to achieve the same?

Comment: Can you post the generated `Test` case class?

Comment: It would be `final case class Test(timeMs: Long, UUID: Option[String]=None) extends ... { ... }`

Comment: @Wallkan I have added the generated case class in the question.

Answer (score 1):

ScalaPB adds a `@SerialVersionUID` annotation to the generated case class. This breaks latest avro4s (2.0.4) due to https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/issues/300

Comment: This is fixed in the latest 3.0.x snapshots, I'd recommend you upgrade to the latest version as found on the avro4s homepage.

Answer (score 1):

avro4s had a [bug](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/issues/300), as @thesamet mentioned, that caused errors when a class would have a Java annotation. ScalaPB added such an annotation - `@SerialVersionUID`. This is fixed in the latest avro4s snapshots (3.0.0.X-snapshot) and will be in the final 3.0.0 release when that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

ScalaPB's generated class contain a lot of boilerplate based on PB runtime library. One of the safest way to convert / read protobuf messages in Avro is to use AvroProtobuf compatibility. You can find more about it on [org.apache.avro.protobuf](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/protobuf/package-summary.html) package.

You can use the `ProtobufData` to get schema or perform SerDe operations.